# Badident error when using "as" in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I have the following code that filters through a table of results:

```
<strong>CLIENTS [ {{ results.length }} ]</strong>
 <thead ng-show="clientSearch">
        <tr>
            <th><i class="fa fa-search"></i></th>
            <th class="search-box">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Name" ng-model="searchResult.firstname">
            </th>
            <th class="search-box">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Surname" ng-model="searchResult.lastname">
            </th>
            <th class="search-box">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Address" ng-model="searchResult.address">
            </th>
            <th class="search-box">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search Email" ng-model="searchResult.email">
            </th>
            <th class="search-box">
                <input type="number" placeholder="Search Mobile" ng-model="searchResult.mobile">
            </th>

            <th class="search-box">
                <input type="date" class="datepicker" placeholder="Search By Date" ng-model="searchResult.registrationDate">
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
```

This is the code the produces the table data:

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients as results  | filter : searchResult " ng-dblclick="open(client)">
            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td>{{client.firstname}}</td>
            <td>{{client.lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{client.address}}</td>
            <td>{{client.email}}</td>
            <td>{{client.mobile}}</td>
            <td>{{client.registrationDate | date: 'medium'}}</td>
            <td ng-if="results.length === 0">NO RESULTS FOUND</td>
        </tr>
```

But I get this error https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/error/ngRepeat/badident when I try to use ngRepeat.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this.

Comment: Why do you need `result`? `client` would hold one element within `clients` already.

Comment: I need to know the number of clients in the ng-repeat

Comment: Did you try `clients.length`?

Comment: @FDavidov Yes I did. But the value will not change after I use filter.

Comment: You will need to explain better what you want to achieve and perhaps add the code of your filter (and explain what the filter is supposed to do).

Comment: @FDavidov just added better explanation.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is faaaaaaarrrr from clear. Sorry, can't help you.

Comment: See [ngRepeat](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), section "Arguments", last supported format:

`For example: "item in items | filter:x as results" will store the fragment of the repeated items as results, but only after the items have been processed through the filter.`